# Maven points to a strange local repository directory

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I try to use Maven from command line or Intellij, it points to a local repository c:\Users\username\subir.m2\repository instead of c:\Users\username.m2\repository . It happens only when I use another Java than the default Java 11.

I checked the settings.xml of maven, but it seems ok. I also added manually the default local repository without success.

On command line, I can force the repo using `-Dmaven.repo.local`. In Intellij I don't know how to point to the correct repository. Settings under Maven -> Repositories are ok.

**EDIT:** as suggested by Anthony, in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven I simply clicked Override near User settings and Local repository, leaving the default values, and it worked.

Of course, on the command line it continues to point to the bad path. Is there not a way to change that, without using everytime `-Dmaven.repo.local`?

Comment: try checking your appData in roaming folder for maven profiled configuration since this one is prior to execution, you may find another configuration in a stand alone setup withing the Appdata of intellij. try a bulk search on this folder for all settings.xml

Comment: I would like to check all the AppData folder ( all neighbour folders of roaming )

Comment: I searched for all settings.xml in my whole hard disk. I found three of them, but none of them have the strange local repo

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can always override the local repository you wants to use following this path :

Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven and then check "Override" to add your custom local repository

[Settings Menu on IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY1zE.png)

You can also precise your local repository by adding this to your setting.xml :
"< localRepository > /Path/Of/Your/Repo < /localRepository >"

Hope it helps

Comment: Okay, simply clicking on override worked on Intellij. Of course on command line it continues to point to the bad path.

Answer (score 0):

In your intellij idea, you can change it from Settings > Maven
[image]

Comment: Settings on Intellij are ok, in the point you write and under Maven -> Repository

Comment: If you want to run it from your powershell, you can try with modifying this command:

`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "E:\jdks\jdk-1.8.0_92");[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "E:\node;E:\maven\apache-maven-3.
3.9\bin;E:\git\git-2.18.0-64-bit\bin;$($Env:JAVA_HOME)\bin;"+ [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine))
`
This command helps us set the paths temporarily. This will help you to understand if your paths are correct. Then you can put the correct value to your System as permanent path